# Angular 12 .Net 6 value null being passed to api as "null"

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an angular 12 UI that is communicating with a .net 6 API. When a parameter in a query string is null or undefined the API is interpreting it as a string value of "null" or "undefined". Relevant code below

angular code:

```
getDummyUser(type: string, testId: string):
Observable<UserDto> {
var url = `api/users/get-dummy-user?type=${encodeURIComponent(type)}&testId=${encodeURIComponent(testId)}`;
return this.httpClient.get<any>(url)
  .pipe(
    finalize(() =>
      this.hideLoadingIndicators()
    ),
    catchError(err => {
      return throwError(err);
    })
  );
```

}

.net 6 api parameter signature

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("get-dummy-user")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDummyUser
        (
        string type, 
        string testId
        )
```

I have tried using the [FromQuery] attribute but the result is the same. I also cannot send '' from the angular app as the API will then throw a 400 error (bad request). Has anyone had any experience in this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't include it in the query string if it is null?

Comment: the API returns a 400 (bad request) I have tried this with the [FromQuery] attribute and without it

Answer (score 2):

Add filter model in Angular and use it to send the request from Angular to .net
example :
FiltersModel.ts

```
export class GetDummy{

    type: string| null
    testId: string |null

  
}
```

Component.ts (where you send the request to backend)

```
 let filters:GetDummy = new GetDummy();
 filters.type="exampleType";
   let filterToSend="";
    Object.entries(filters).forEach(res=>{
      filterToSend+="&"+res[0]+"="+res[1];
   
    }); 
     var url='api/users/get-dummy-user?'+filterToSend);
```

And with this the request will be

```
http//:api/users/get-dummy-user?type="exampleType"
```

it's a way to send only the needed options to backend and the testId will be not be send as options

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is something to do with new .net 6 or angular 12 but it appears that nowadays you have to send an empty string as the parameter AND make string nullable on the .net side. I'm not sure why string has to be declared as nullable now when it is... inherently nullable. Having issues with code formatting, apologies. Working solution below

```
getDummyUser(type) {
  this.userProvider.getDummyUser(type, '').subscribe(u => {
});




getDummyUser(type: string, testId: string):Observable<UserDto> {var url = `api/users/get-dummy-usertype=${encodeURIComponent(type)}&testId=${encodeURIComponent(testId)}`;return this.httpClient.get<any>(url).pipe(
finalize(() =>
  this.hideLoadingIndicators()
),
catchError(err => {
  return throwError(err);
})
```

);

```
  [HttpGet]
[Route("get-dummy-user")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDummyUser
    (
    [FromQuery] string type, 
    [FromQuery] string? testId
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export interface IGetDummy{
type: string;
testId?: string;
```

}

```
   sendingParams=[
//what u send as parameter to thi Api
]



 getDummyUser(params:Params):{

    return this.http.get<IGetDummy>(url,{observe:'response', sendingParams})
      .pipe(
        finalize(()=>{
          this.hideLoadingIndicators();
        },catchError(err => {
  return throwError(err);
      )

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).